# The page has expired due to inactivity. Why?

Tags: laravel, windows-10, homestead

I have a problem. I have 2 computers, the first is Ubuntu and the second is Windows 10. Both computers have a bundle of Vagrant + VirtualBox + Homestead. On a computer with Ubuntu, everything works fine, and on a computer with Windows 10 when I try to send a form to the server, I get the status 419 and the message:

The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.

The CSRF token is updated every time the page is refreshed. This is a clean installation of Laravel + **php artisan make:auth** and **php artisan migrate** (default tables) in the clean Homestead environment on both PC. The rights to the session directory are full, the user is vagrant, the group is vagrant. Session file is created.**.env** files are identical (standard), except for the name of the database. What could be the problem? I really need your help!

All the advice on a similar problem did not help me. Cache view, config, etc. i cleaned, the key generated anew. The browser cache was cleaned, cookies checked - on the spot. The only difference between the two computers is the operating system, but does it matter when Laravel is on the Homestead virtual machine?

Comment: are you inactive more than 2 hours ?

Comment: No, this fresh installation of the project and inactivity was not (if I correctly understood your question, I have a bad English, I use an interpreter)

Comment: I recorded a [video](https://youtu.be/cooy3uzGy-k)

Answer (score 0):

From your video, change the **APP_NAME** in your .env file to something other than ‘Laravel’.

I would bet, you have other sites running under the same local URL that have the same APP_NAME.

Changing the APP_NAME changes the session cookie name in **config/sessions.php**

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),
```

You can manually override the cookie name by setting the SESSION_COOKIE variable in your .env file OR let it fallback to the calculated slug above that utilizes the app name (2nd parameter).

Google Chrome is the only browser this happens in for some reason. I spent almost a year trying to figure this problem out and this was the solution!

Comment: I did as you said before reinstalling VirtualBox, and my application worked! After I reinstalled VirtualBox, I changed APP_NAME, the forms started to send successfully and the token stopped changing, after which I returned APP_NAME back to Laravel and the application continued to function normally! Based on simple logs I can judge what helped reinstall VirtualBox, what say?

Comment: I deployed another application near the previous one. APP_ENV for both applications - Laravel. Everything works perfectly.

It's scary when the problem is solved by a simple software reinstallation, there is no real understanding of the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

- Add the route entry in *app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php*

protected $except = [
'your/route'
];

If you have **already** included the CSRF token in your form. Then you are getting the error page possibly beacuse of cache data in your form. Open your terminal / command prompt and run these commands in your project root.

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan route:clear
4. php artisan view:clear

Also try to **clear the browser cache** along with running these commands.

- Make sure the session secure value in file *app / config / session.php* is set to false.

  'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),